Average Area of Circumcircle of Randomly Inscribed Triangle

Choose points $A, B, C$ independently and uniformly distributed on the perimeter of a unit circle, and create $\triangle ABC$. Is there a better method (than the one presented below) to prove that the expected area of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$ is $\pi$?

$A$ can be assigned coordinates $(1,0)$ without loss of generality. Let the central angles from $A$ to $B$ and $A$ to $C$ be $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Due to symmetry, we can place restrictions on these angles: $0 \leq \theta_1 \leq \pi$ and $0 \leq \theta_2 < 2\pi$. Note that $B$ and $C$ have coordinates $(\cos\theta_1, \sin\theta_1)$ and $(\cos\theta_2, \sin\theta_2)$.
The equation for the area of $\triangle ABC$, given $\theta_1, \theta_2$, is
$$A(\theta_1, \theta_2) = 2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_1)\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_2)\sin(\frac{1}{2}[\theta_1-\theta_2])$$
The equations for the lengths of the segments $a, b, \text{and } c$ (the sides opposite from their respective vertex) can be derived from distance formula.
$$\begin{cases} a = \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_1}\\
b = \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_2}\\
c = \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} \end{cases}$$
The formula for the radius of the circumcircle is $\frac{abc}{4A}$, where $a,b,c$ are sidelengths, and $A$ is the area of the triangle. Thus, in terms of $\theta_i$, the radius of the circumcenter is
$$\frac{abc}{4A(\theta_1, \theta_2)} = \frac{\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_1}\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_2}\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}}{4|2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_1)\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_2)\sin(\frac{1}{2}[\theta_1-\theta_2])|}$$
The entire 2-dimensional space described by $\theta_1, \theta_2$ can be calculated as
$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta_2 d\theta_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}$. Hence, the average radius of the circumcircle for all valid combinations of $\theta_1, \theta_2$can be calculated from the following double integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2}{\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_1}\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos\theta_2}\sqrt{2 - 2 \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}}{4|2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_1)\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_2)\sin(\frac{1}{2}[\theta_1-\theta_2])|}}d\theta_2 d\theta_1$$
Recall the trigonometric identity (from double-angle identity for $\cos \theta$): $2-2\cos\theta = 4\sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})$. We can simplify the numerator of our integral, miraculously giving
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2}{\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2\sin(\frac{\theta_1}{2})2\sin(\frac{\theta_2}{2})2\sin(\frac{\theta_1 - \theta_2}{2})}{4|2\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_1)\sin(\frac{1}{2}\theta_2)\sin(\frac{1}{2}[\theta_1-\theta_2])|}}d\theta_2 d\theta_1$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 1 d\theta_2 d\theta_1 = 1$$
The average (or expected) radius of the circumcircle of an randomly inscribed triangle in a unit circle is 1. Thus, the expected area of the circumcircle will be $\pi(1)^2 = \pi$. Is there another method that rigorously proves this result?
Thanks.

Isn't the circumcircle of ABC the unit circle itself? $\quad$ Otherwise, note that you want $E(\pi r^2)$, which is NOT the same as $\pi E(r)^2$, unless in very unique situations.
